# Map<IDataReader, MyType>(sourceReader, destinationObject) not updating destinationObject

Tags: automapper

From the DataReaderMapping unit test, change the Establish_context method (the Mapper.Map line)

```
        protected override void Establish_context()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<IDataRecord, DTOObject>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Else, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.GetDateTime(src.GetOrdinal(FieldName.Something))));

            _dataRecord = new DataBuilder().BuildDataRecord();
            var result = new DTOObject();
            Mapper.Map<IDataRecord, DTOObject>(_dataRecord, result);
            _result = result;
        }
```

I've tracked it down to the MapPropertyValues method in DataReaderMapper.cs.

The context.TypeMap.GetPropertyMaps() does not have property maps for any properties other than the 'Else' defined in the ForMember extension in the unit test.

I've tried using ForAllMembers to 'trick' the property maps into adding the missing properties, but there are no _sourceValueResolvers for these property maps.

Suggestions on how to address?

Comment: Why don't use a micro ORM? There are a good number of them and do exactly what you need: map a reader to a poco

Comment: that is true.  I would rather do that that but I am limited by other 'environmental' factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IL emitted in DataReaderMapper.CreateBuilder always creates a new object instead of possibly using the DestinationValue within the ResolutionContext.

pull request for AutoMapper 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/721/files